# Can you test replaykit in the simulator in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, replaykit

Im in the ipad air 2 simulator and trying to test replaykit and see if the window pops up to view the video of the recorded screen. When I do that I get an error saying this. Is that because Im testing it in the simulator?

> plugin com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension interrupted
>
> Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.ReplayKit.RPVideoEditorExtension}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well in the simulator. It breaks in there. On-device it's fine. Searching the internet this seems to always be the case.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I thought I was doing it wrong for the iPads.