# Replay Kit IOS not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, replaykit

I tried code on simulator iOS-10 with this link

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-replaykit--cms-25458

But code is not working. Its not showing any window asking for the options.

Completion handler for the start is called but when I tap on stop its completion handler not getting called.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this also happen od device? This ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490555/can-you-test-replaykit-in-the-simulator-in-xcode ) suggests that ReplayKit won't work on simulator.

Comment: I don't have device to test. If any one can let me know that would be of great help.

Comment: Code works well on device but not on Simulator .

Comment: The same thing happens to me on the simulator, but works fine on a device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replay kit doesn't work on IOS Simulator but works well on Actual Device.
I have tried this with IOS 8 and 9. SO this issue is with Simulator.

Thanks